# Turning on linum-mode when in python/c mode

Tags: emacs, python-mode, c-mode

I want to turn on linum mode (M-x linum-mode) automatically with python and c mode.
I add the following code in .emacs, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (line-number-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)

(defun my-python-mode-common-hook ()
  (line-number-mode 1))
(add-hook 'python-mode-common-hook 'my-python-mode-common-hook)
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`line-number-mode` and `linum-mode` are not the same.

Try this:

```
(defun my-c-mode-hook () 
  (linum-mode 1)) 
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook) 

(defun my-python-mode-hook () 
  (linum-mode 1)) 
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work after the change. Is there any way to debug what might be wrong?

Comment: Remove the common from the hook name. I fixed the code above.

Answer (score 15):

You also have the option of setting linum-mode globally.

```
;; In your .emacs
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

**Edit:**
In my configuration I have `global-linum-mode` active and inhibit it for certain major modes:

```
(setq linum-mode-inhibit-modes-list '(eshell-mode
                                      shell-mode
                                      erc-mode
                                      jabber-roster-mode
                                      jabber-chat-mode
                                      gnus-group-mode
                                      gnus-summary-mode
                                      gnus-article-mode))

(defadvice linum-on (around linum-on-inhibit-for-modes)
  "Stop the load of linum-mode for some major modes."
    (unless (member major-mode linum-mode-inhibit-modes-list)
      ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'linum-on)
```

Answer (score 3):

All major mode for programming languages derive from prog-mode, so
`(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)` will enable linum-mode for all programming modes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what hooks C-mode is supposed to use (never used C-mode), but this should do what you want:

```
(dolist (hook '(python-mode-hook
            c-mode-common-hook))
  (add-hook hook (lambda () (linum-mode t))))
```