# Line numbers only in certain modes

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Is there a way to get line numbering only in specific modes, i.e Python, Java, C++, etc., rather than in every window? I thought I saw something about this the other day, but I can't find it.

Currently I'm set up that the default is just to have `linum-mode` on persistenly. It's kind of annoying in the shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't turn `linum` on globally.

Instead I turn `linum` on for the major mode in which I want it.  For example:

```lisp
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook '(lambda () (linum-on)))
```

or simply:

```lisp
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
```

Related here:

[Turning on linum-mode when in python/c mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875213/turning-on-linum-mode-when-in-python-c-mode)

and here:

[Emacs Org-Mode: Turn off line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229705/emacs-org-mode-turn-off-line-numbers)

Comment: Good links. Thank you.

Comment: You can simplify this to ```(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'linum-mode)```.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you want to use it all major programming modes and you're using Emacs 24.x, you can use this snippet:

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
```

Comment: 'prog-mode-hook has got to be the coolest thing since sliced bread.  Thanks so much for this!